# HTML/CSS Hover over image for close up image/test/hyperlink

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm building a resource website for the facility I work and need help with a script.

I have an image of multiple medications that i'd like to hover to display more info. The following link is an example i found online.

[image link](http://www.ucdmc.ucdavis.edu/cppn/resources/clinical_skills_refresher/crash_cart/graphics/Medications.jpg)

I'd like to be able to hover each medication to have a window pop up next to it with a close up image, the name of the drug, and a hyper link to an external site. What would the easiest way to achieve this.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Have you tried anything urself?

Comment: You could probably do it using a tooltips plugin.

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet, before i did. I wanted to get your opinions. I'll check out tooltip. thanks!

Comment: Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/chin/2y4s4/

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to give a "good" answer without seeing what the actual data is you wish to display. However from what you have provided the most accessible method would be to use an HTML image map.

Here are the MDN docs for the separate HTML elements you will need to use:

[Map link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map)

[Area link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/area)

Essentially you define rectangles, circles or polygons (using coordinates) which "overlay" the associated image. Each area can have an *alt* attribute which screen readers will be able to use for those viewing your site with visual impairments. The `href` attribute will provide you with the link to the external site.

Now there are several offline tools that can help you create image maps, here is an [online one](http://www.image-maps.com/) ...I am not necessarily recommending it over others, however it will provide you with an idea of how they work.

Once you have the accessible version in place, you can use JavaScript to provide extra functionality on top of that. How you wish to do that is really up to you, and again would be defined by the exact content you wish to display, and there are several pre made scripts out there for the purpose, however if you were simply wanting to display the `alt`/href in a basic tooltip then it wouldn't require more than a few lines of bespoke HTML/JavaScript.

Again, without recommending them, here are a couple of common solutions:

[solution 1](http://qtip2.com/) and [solution 2](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/)

Even if this is not exactly what you are looking for, it should provide you with some help at deciding your final solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use an image map and some javascript mouse event action. The main image is an image map with rectangular/circular 'area' regions. Infos are put into 'div' blocks that are made visible/invisible with style property 'display' set to 'block' or 'none'. The init() function makes all 'div' blocks invisible at start.

HTML:

```
<img src="XYZ" alt="medications" usemap="#medsMap">
<map name="medsMap">
<area shape="rect" coords="x,y,w,h" onmouseover="showInfo('med1')" onmouseout="hideInfo('med1')" >
<area shape="circle" coords="x,y,r" onmouseover="showInfo('med2')" onmouseout="hideInfo('med2')" >
</map>

<div class="medInfo" id="med1">
// All your html about medication 1
</div>
<div class="medInfo" id="med2">
// All your html about medication 2
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
window.onload = init;

function init(){
    var infos = document.getElementsByClassName('medInfo');
    for (var i=0, i<infos.length, i++){
        infos[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
}

function showInfo(divId){
    document.getElementById('med1').style.display = 'block'
}

function hideInfo(divId){
    document.getElementById('med1').style.display = 'none'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

easiest may not be the best in the case... however a simple solution would be something with abosolute positioned divs inside a relative positioned container div with the image set to the background. you could assign a click handler to each one to grab the data from an object and populate the target... the data might look something like this

```
var myItems = {
    item1: {
        img: 'http://www.photo-dictionary.com/photofiles/list/6666/8841blue_pill.jpg',
        headline: 'the blue pill',
        body: 'this pill is blue and comes in a purple box'
    },
    item2: {
        img: 'http://www.photo-dictionary.com/photofiles/list/6679/8857red_pill.jpg',
        headline: 'the red pill',
        body: 'this pill is red and comes in a red box'
    }
};
```

here is an example of that concept in a fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/pixelchemist/3fL8P/